# Erro ao tentar criar uma Controller ou ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Criei um projeto Asp.Net Core 2.0 vazio(sem scaffold). Modelo DDD e etc. Porem quando tento criar minha controller, seja herdada de ApiController ou Controller, dá erro:

> Controller é um namespace, mas é usado como um tipo

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Message")]
public class MessageController : Controller
{
}
```

No exemplo acima eu tentei criar uma ApiController e veio da forma acima.

Comment: No core ele herda apenas `Controller`. Você não criou, acidentalmente, algum `namespace` **Controller**?

Comment: Altere o nome da pasta para Controllers e namespace para Controllers

Comment: @NetinhoSantos, responde que eu marco. Era o nome da pasta mesmo.

Comment: @pnet respondido. Att.

Comment: Ultimamente só down, tá osso. Foi ficar uns dias sem abrir o site que agora é só down, apesar que tem um cara no site que sempre me dá DownVote, independente da construção da pergunta, mas isso é outro assunto.

Comment: Veja também o *ASP NET Core 2 Razor Pages*, que simplifica ainda mais isto.

Comment: valeu @Tony, vou dar uma estudada sim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altere o nome da pasta para Controllers e namespace para Controllers.

```
namespace MeuApp.Controllers
{
   public class MessageController : Controller
   {
       // Seu código...
   }
}
```